# C#: Handling combination of errors in return value

Tags: c#, error-handling, return-value

I have a feeling this may be stupid question, but I can't come to the simple solution that I'm sure exists.

I have a C# class that validates a configuration file against some other file.

There may be two kinds of errors, which are represented in an enum:

```
public enum ErrorType
{
    VersionsMismatch,
    UnsupportedCombination
}
```

There is a struct representing the error:

```
 public struct ValiditionResult
    {
        public bool Valid { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public ErrorType ErrorType { get; set; }
        public List<ConfProperties> InvalidProperties {get;set;}
    }
```

The function interface look like this:

```
 public ValiditionResult Validate(string confFile, string progFile)
```

The struct represents the fixes required in the files.

So if there are two types of fixes, it should be specified.

What is the best way to indicate all the errors occured (there may be more than two in the future)?

To return a list of the ValidationResult struct? to make some XOR of the Enum? Any other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mark your enum with the attribute [Flags]

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx for more info.

Comment: More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx Look under Enumeration Types as Bit Flags.

Comment: Flags are great, I use them all the time. However, you have to know your developer audience. If a lot of new developers will be looking at this code, you may want to go with a List instead. Using bit-wise operators with [Flags] enums can be confusing to look at, and they may misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would be a good choice for a packaged exception. You do your validation and create the exceptions to throw, then throw that aggregate exception:

```
public IEnumerable<Exception> Validate(string configFile, string programFile)
{
    if(...)
      yield return new VersionsMismatchException(...);

    if(...)
      yield return new UnsupportedCombinationException(...);
}
```

Then you have a method which takes all the exceptions and then packages them for throw:

```
public void EnsureConfigurationIsValid(string configFile, string programFile)
{
    var exceptions = Validate(configFile, programFile).ToList();

    if(exceptions.Count > 0)
       throw new ValidationFailedException(exceptions); // creates an internal list
}
```

Then whatever method you are calling this validate method from simply needs to have a `try/catch` block to handle the aggregate exception and loop through each exception of your aggregate and handle them.

Adding new rules then simply becomes another condition in your validate method with a new yield statement.

Each individual exception can have properties and data specific to that guy, and it can set it's own message to display, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If `ValidationResult` captures the information about the outcome of a single validation rule, it would make sense to return `List<ValidationResult>`.

You could then determine whether validation failed overall with something like `results.Any(vr => !vr.Valid)`.

Also, is there something done in code to resolve validation failures? Does the enum drive how/where a results are packaged and delivered by your code? I am wondering what the enumeration achieves.